# Phpdocumentor and Slim routers documentation

Tags: php, routes, documentation, slim, phpdoc

I use phpdocumentor for generating of documentation for my project. It generates good documentation for my functions like:

```
    /**
       * Hash generator
       *
       * Long description
       *
       * @param string $password Password
       * @return string
       */
    function generate_hash($password) {
        global $PASSWORD_SALT;
        return crypt($password, $PASSWORD_SALT);
    }
```

but i have not found a way for documenting mappings for slim (php framework):

```
    /**
     * Delete news
     *
     * Delete news by id
     *
     * @link /news/delete/:id
     *
     */
    $app->get('/news/delete/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
        $item = ORM::for_table('news')->find_one($id);
        if ($item)
            $item->delete();
        $app->redirect('/');
    })->conditions(array('id'=>'\d+'));
```

What is right way to document things like this?

Comment: API usage is not part of API documentation. You could wrap the code in a function or method, and return the results.

Answer (score 0):

To describe my comment as an answer I'd point you towards something similiar to:

```
/**
 * Delete news
 *
 * Delete news by id
 *
 * @link /news/delete/:id
 *
 */
public function deleteNewsByID (&$app, $id)
{
     return $app->get('/news/delete/:id', function ($id) use ($app) {
         $item = ORM::for_table('news')->find_one($id);
         if ($item)
             $item->delete();
         $app->redirect('/');
     })->conditions(array('id'=>'\d+'));
}
```

But I am not familiar with slim so I cannot insure this will work at all. And it is not recommended nor pretty, as stated in the comments below.

Comment: changing the code to let the 'automatic documentation' work, sounds like "putting the cart before the horse"

Comment: Yep, but it is the only way to document this in documentor or apigen. I never said it was pretty, nor do I understand why someone would want to document this other than in the source code.

Comment: there are several reasons. sometimes you have to work with 3rd party programmers, who do not have access to the source code of the api, but still they need documentation to code their clients.

Comment: its a really common use case of Slim framework to build a REST API, and consumers of that API need an API doc. pretty straight forward.